# How can I build a 'has-many-through' relation linking more than 2 models?

Tags: php, orm, kohana, has-many-through

I have 3 models eg;

```
TABLE `users`
    `id` INT
    `username` VARCHAR(32)
    ...

TABLE `books`
    `id` INT
    `title` VARCHAR(100)
    `author` INT (foreign ket constraint)

TABLE `rights`
    `id` INT
    `name` VARCHAR(32)
```

Now I want a user to have particular rights to eg. read or edit a book. So the rights table should look like (much like ORM roles table):

```
|----|------|
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | view |
| 2  | edit |
| .. | ...  |
```

And I would have a fourth table linking all three;

```
TABLE user_book_rights
|---------|---------|----------|
| user_id | book_id | right_id |
|---------|---------|----------|
|    1    |    1    |    2     |
|    1    |    2    |    1     |
|    2    |    1    |    1     |
|   ...   |   ...   |   ...    |
```

So if a user wants to, say, read a book, I want to check if the logged in user with id 1, has the right with id 1 for book with id 2.

But how the heck can I achieve this with ORM? Of course I can just write my own query;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `has_right` FROM `user_book_rights` WHERE user_id=1 AND book_id=2 AND right_id=1

if($result['has_right']) {
    echo 'Yeah, read the book!';
} else {
    echo 'Sorry mate, this book is not for dummies...';
}
```

But I'd rather do something like:

```
$has_right = $user->has('book_rights', ORM::factory('user_book_right', array('book_id' => '2', 'right_id' => 1));
```

Or even better:

```
$book = ORM::factory('book', 1);
$right = ORM::factory('right', array('name' => 'view'));
$has_right = $user->has('book_rights', ORM::factory('user_book_right', array($book, $right)));
```

I could not find an answer to my question. Is it weird to want to link three models as a many_through realtionship? Or is ORM just not capable and should I write my own query?

Thanks ia. for your insights!

Comment: Maybe looking at how a popular ORM such as Doctrine handles these situations would help? http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: I think it's not possible with 3.2 (at least not by default). 3.3 will probably support this.

Comment: hmzz... too bad... for now i'll fix this by writing the query's myself. When i'll find some time after this project i might fork my own implementation of this! thanks for your advice guys!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer does not help you a lot. But i suggest that you encode the right in bit representation.

```
READ = 00000001 = 1
EDIT = 00000010 = 2
DELETE = 0000100 = 4
```

than, if a user has the write to read, edit and delete
you just do

```
READ | EDIT | DELETE = 0000111 = 7
```

If you want to test if a user has a particular right you just do:
if ($user_write & READ) { // he can read}

Maybe if you use this design, and eliminate the rights table with those constants, it may help you.

Comment: oldskool unix :) it's a pretty good solution, the only downside is that i cannot save some meta data about the rights right into the table (or i should create a table where i insert the bit-rights, but that will leave me with the same problem ;))